# My question is that why Modern spiritual person kept hair long?

Tags: guru

I see  why   present spiritual person  like   Sri ravi shankar, shadhguru etc  have long hairs  ?  they can  cut their hair   as there are many  salon available in market...But  In  ancient times  Rishi   were kept hair long  because  there is no salon available  at that   times

My  question is  that   why   Modern  spiritual  person  kept hair long ?
Is there  any reason  why they  kept their hair long ?

Comment: Rishis don't cut hair because for them the skull in head won't be hard like us and will become soft extremely due to intense yogic practice. If one cuts hair in that stage, any slight error during that time In head will cause Atma to leave the body instantly

Comment: Which spiritual people are you talking about? Neo-Vedantins? Sannyasis are supposed to either shave their head (if balding) or cut the rest of their hair and keep the sikha (top-knot).

Comment: Because, hair increases one's aura and perseverance in spiritual path. Hairs are extensions of body nerves and acts like antenna for a sage while syncing with the cosmic consciousness. It also increases valor in men like lion is bravest animal has its mane full of hairs. Sikhs and Nazirite(like Samson) grow hair for the same reason that is increased strength and spirituality.